# How can I indicate to my bootstrapper that load modules from a folder and in memory?

Tags: c#, prism, mef, bootstrapping

In my MEF application, I plan to load modules from two ways.

One way would be like this.

```
    protected override void ConfigureAggregateCatalog()
    {
        this.AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(PEMDAS.ModuleInit).Assembly));
        this.AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(Bootstrapper).Assembly));
        this.AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(Infrastructure.ObservableCommand).Assembly));
        this.AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(Security.SecurityModule).Assembly));
        this.AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(Tests.ModuleInit).Assembly));
    }
```

And the another would be looking for the assemblies inside a folder. I supposed that can be used these two ways. I plan to load first the folder and then the `ConfigureAggregateCatalog`.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly you are wondering how to load modules from .dll assemblies in a folder. This can be done with a [DirectoryCatalog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.hosting.directorycatalog.aspx).

```
//First create directory catalog and load modules from .dlls.
var dirCatalog = new DirectoryCatalog(folderToSearch, "*.dll");
this.AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(dirCatalog);

//Next load the rest of the modules.
ConfigureAggregateCatalog();
```